# Spring Integration aggregator when last record filters

Tags: spring, integration, aggregator

We have a Spring Integration project where one large input file is burst into many individual files and then aggregated back together using the Spring Integration Aggregator.

There are a number of filters in the pipeline that will filter out unwanted individual files. We keep track of the number of files filtered for each correlated input file. Our @ReleaseStrategy checks to see if we have received the number of individual files minus the number of filtered individual files.

What will happen if the last individual file to be processed is filtered before it hits our ReleaseStrategy? The ReleaseStrategy is called for each individual file that reaches it, I would not be polled again if the last individual file is filtered, but I would also expect Spring to have anticipated this use case and made some non-hackish provision for it that still provides me with the @Aggregator event. I don't get an @Aggregator event if I timeout or if I cause all the filter points to check to see if they are the last file.

Thanks!

Comment: We have confirmed test flakiness depending on order of events, we need to work around this. I see the ReleaseStrategy receives the full list of messages up to that point, just as the Aggregator does. Our Aggregator is going to need to hold state, to remember the last parameters to ReleaseStrategyso we can fake a call to Aggregator. I will not mark this as the answer to the question as I still hold hope that someone will come up with a Spring approved "right way" to do this, but I suspect it is a hole in the Spring Integration architecture when combining filtering with aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to the Split-filter-aggregate pattern was to set the following properties on the aggregator bean.

```
send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"
group-timeout="5000"
```

These two properties work together to handle situations exactly like the one described, where our ReleaseStrategy is never called with the last record because the last record was filtered. These settings will cause whatever is queued up to release once the timeout is reached.

The timeout is a "quiet period", if no messages for a given CorrelationStrategy are received within the timeout then the aggregate releases. Each message received resets the timeout. See section (21):
http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/